# hash methods argument values

Tags: ruby

Working on trying to understand the syntax for calling on different values of a hash.
For example lets say I am trying to delete 'pants' How do go about setting the argument for something like this:

```
products = {124 => ['shoes', 59.99], 352 => ['shirt', 19.99], 777 => ['pants', 19.87],
667 => ['jacket', 39.99], 898 => ['shoulder_holster', 22.78]}
```

While writing a menu driven program for this hash I'm including error checking before deleteing or adding a key this is what I have so far:

```
if a == 3                    # Loop delete a Product
 puts "Delete a Product"
 d = gets.to_s    # Get value for argument

   while products.has_value?(   d + syntax for right here????    )!= true do
   puts "This turned out false because product does not exsist!"
   d = gets.to_s
   end

 puts "Congrats your out of the loop"
 products.delete(d + again syntax problems ???? )
 puts products
```

end

How do I enter the syntax for the argument if I where to delete pants. Would it be ([d,:number]) I'm not having luck with any resources online with how to delete or add in this scenario. Any help or code example would be appreciated,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether the user is inputing the ID number or the name "pants". If the former:

```
if a == 3                    # Loop delete a Product
  puts "Delete a Product"
  d = gets    # Get value for argument

  until products.has_key?(d.to_i)
    puts "This turned out false because product does not exsist!"
    d = gets
  end

  puts "Congrats your out of the loop"
  products.delete(d.to_i)
  puts products
end
```

If it's "pants", then this is how you want to do it:

```
if a == 3                    # Loop delete a Product
  puts "Delete a Product"
  d = gets.strip    # Need to strip because otherwise the newline will wreck it

  until products.find {|key, val| val.first == d}
    puts "This turned out false because product does not exsist!"
    d = gets.strip
  end

  puts "Congrats your out of the loop"
  products.delete_if {|key, val| val.first == d}
  puts products
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
products.to_a.select {|a| a.last.first == 'pants' }
```

That will get you the record that matches 'pants'.

```
[[777, ["pants", 19.87]]]
```

So I think you'll want

```
while !products.to_a.select {|a| a.last.first == d }.empty?
```

on your loop then use Dafydd's line to delete the record.

Answer (score 1):

**Writing a "delete named product from hash" method**

There are shorter ways of doing it, but shooting for clarity I came up with this:

```
products = {124 => ['shoes', 59.99], 352 => ['shirt', 19.99], 777 => ['pants', 19.87],
667 => ['jacket', 39.99], 898 => ['shoulder_holster', 22.78]}

def wipeProduct(hash, nameToDelete) 
  hash.each do |i| 
    key = i[0]
    productName = i[1].first
    hash.delete(key) if productName==nameToDelete
  end
end

puts products.inspect
wipeProduct(products,'pants')
puts products.inspect
wipeProduct(products,'shoulder_holster')
puts products.inspect

bash-3.2$ ruby prod.rb 
{352=>["shirt", 19.99], 898=>["shoulder_holster", 22.78], 667=>["jacket", 39.99], 777=>["pants", 19.87], 124=>["shoes", 59.99]}
{352=>["shirt", 19.99], 898=>["shoulder_holster", 22.78], 667=>["jacket", 39.99], 124=>["shoes", 59.99]}
{352=>["shirt", 19.99], 667=>["jacket", 39.99], 124=>["shoes", 59.99]}
```

I don't know if it's possible for "pants" to occur in the hash in multiple places, but since I used "hash.each(...)", the method wipeProduct(hash, nameToDelete) will test every hash entry.

**The input type bug and how to fix it**

When you take input, you're assigning the string you captured to d. Here's the proof:

```
irb(main):010:0> d = gets.to_s
12
=> "12\n"
irb(main):011:0> d.class
=> String
```

You can convert that string to a Fixnum like this:

```
irb(main):012:0> d.to_i
=> 12
irb(main):013:0> d.to_i.class
=> Fixnum
```

All keys in the products hash are Fixnums. Here's the proof:

```
irb(main):014:0> products.keys.each {|i| puts i.class}
Fixnum
Fixnum
Fixnum
Fixnum
Fixnum
=> [352, 898, 667, 777, 124]
```

So you need to capture the value for the argument with this line:

```
d = gets.to_i    # Get value for argument
```

**The deletion part of the answer:**

From products, you can delete the pants entry programmatically with this:

products.delete(777)

Running it gets you this:

```
irb(main):003:0> products.delete(777)
=> ["pants", 19.87]
```

Notice that you supply the key value (in this case 777) to .delete() and that it returns an array consisting of the key and value in that order respectively.

**An alternative implementation**

I'm not sure if it's safe to modify a hash in a block that's iterating over the key-value pairs in the hash. If it isn't, you can just save up all the keys to be deleted and delete them after iterating over the hash:

```
def wipeProduct(hash, nameToDelete) 
  keysToDelete = []
  hash.each do |i| 
    key = i[0]
    productName = i[1].first
    keysToDelete << key if productName==nameToDelete
  end
  keysToDelete.each {|key| hash.delete(key) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the neater way to delete the "pants" entry:

```
def wipeProduct(hash, nameToDelete)
  hash.reject!{|key,value| nameToDelete==value.first}
end
```

The reject! block gets to see each key-value pair, and when it returns true, the key-value supplied will be removed from the hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
if a == 3                    # Loop delete a Product
 puts "Delete a Product by its key number"
 d = gets
 while products.has_key?(d)!= false do
   puts "You have selected a key that is not currently in use"
   d = gets
 end
 puts "You have deleted"
 products.delete(d)
 puts products
end
```

This is what I ended up doing had some trouble with the until loop so swapped for a while loop though becasue it wouldn't accept newly entered keys for some reason

Comment: btw thanks for all the info guys sure helps rather then pulling hair out